# How can I build a custom request workflow in Postman, based on the last request's response?

Tags: postman, azure-logic-apps

I have a request that needs some time to be processed in Logic Apps, so I established an [async pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply). Then, in the response (a 202 status type) there is a "location" header value that has a URL value like the following:

> https://example.com/checkJobId/218764

The server returns a response with the "location" and "retry-after" header values, and I want Postman to go into that location with the same credentials until it comes back with a 200 response. Is there a way to do this?

I checked in [the documentation](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/#scripting-workflows) that you can chain different requests by name or ID; maybe the only solution is to separate the Job ID as a "job-id" value at the response's header and pass it to a new request under my collections in Postman, but I want to know if I can do it directly without having to change my server's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done. This is my tested and working postman code:

```js
// VARIABLES
var jobUrl = "https://example.com/api/async-task";
var retries = 5;
var delayInSecondsBetweenRetries = 20;

// Send initial request and get response
pm.sendRequest({
    url: jobUrl,
    method: "POST",
    header: {
        "APIKey": "MYAPIKEY"
    },
}, function(err, res) {
    var location = res.headers.get("location");
    console.log("Job started. Checking status at: " + location);
    
    // If status code 202 is received, get the "location" header URL
    if (res.status == "Accepted") {

        console.log("Entering in retry loop");
        // Start retry loop
        for (var i = 0; i < retries; i++) {

            (function(i) {
                var delay = delayInSecondsBetweenRetries * 1000 * i;
                var friendlyStatus = "Still Working";
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Send request to "location" header URL and get response
                    pm.sendRequest({
                        url: location,
                        method: "GET",
                        header: {
                            "APIKey": "MYAPIKEY"
                            },
                    }, function(err, res) {
                        if (res.status == "Accepted") {
                            friendlyStatus = "Still Working";
                        } else if (res.status == "Bad Request") {
                            friendlyStatus = "Job ID not found or some error happened in the server!";
                        } else if (res.status == "OK") {
                            friendlyStatus = "||||||| Job Done! ||||||||";
                        } else {
                            throw new Error("An unknown response was recieved. Check the console for details.");
                        }
                        console.log("Location checked. Response: " + friendlyStatus);

                        // If status code 200 is received, exit loop
                        if (res.status == "OK") {
                            var response = res.json();

                            console.log("Response: " + response.ResponseText + "\n" + "Full Response Data: " + response.FullResponseData);

                        }

                        // If status code is not 200, wait 10 seconds and retry
                        else if (res.status == "Accepted") {
                            var messageComplement = "Retrying in " + delayInSecondsBetweenRetries + " seconds";
                            if (i == 9) {
                                messageComplement = "Achieved retries limit. No more retries.";
                            }
                            console.log(messageComplement);
                        }

                        else if (res.status == "Accepted") {
                            var messageComplement = "Retrying in " + delayInSecondsBetweenRetries + " seconds";
                            if (i == 9) {
                                messageComplement = "Achieved retries limit. No more retries.";
                            }
                            console.log(messageComplement);
                        }
                    });
                }, delay);

            })(i)
            
        }
    }
});
```